# java SimpleDateFormat wrongly parse given timestamp

Tags: java, date, time, timestamp

when I run the following code:

```
package testframe;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class dates {

    public static void handleLastValueDate()  {

        Timestamp stamp = new Timestamp(1490018838);
        Date date = new Date(stamp.getTime());
         SimpleDateFormat df =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        handleLastValueDate();

    }

}
```

I get the following result: `1970-01-18 07:53` which is incorrect and should be

```
GMT: Mon, 20 Mar 2017 12:55:38 GMT
Your time zone: 3/20/2017, 2:55:38 PM GMT+2:00
```

can anyone please explain for me why this is happening? I tired to play with locale but also that didn't help! how can I see the correct time?

thanks.

Comment: You never use DateFormat in your code. How it can be wrong?

Comment: the expected result is a completely different format as to what you specified in the simpledateFormat ?

Comment: I don't see a print statement anywhere.

Comment: Q: what does that line do?
'SimpleDateFormat df =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");' A: it sets the format you are getting which is the format used in 1970-01-18 07:53...

Comment: You're missing 3 digits from the long representation of your date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is printing **1970-01-18 07:53** because you need to multiply 1490018838 by 1000 (milliseconds), on the other hand, no need to use the TimeStamp, Date class has an overloaded Constructor taking the epoch in milliseconds

```
Date date = new Date(1490019439L * 1000);
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
System.out.println(df.format(date));
```

be awware also about this.

```
new Date(1490019439L * 1000)
```

am using the timeStamp as Long literal, if you dont, then an overflow in the integer will happens and you will get again a wrong date...

Comment: can I use the timestamp given as input to format method?

Comment: and thanks for your quick answer :)